# Gatling fails to login to the application

Tags: performance, cookies, gatling

When I execute my script login to the application is successful. I get all the cookies which are then send with next requests (every request looks the same as in the browser), but next step fails. The step which fails is request “user”. I get 302 instead of 200. Any idea what can be wrong in my scenario? Maybe it is the problem with cookie policy, for example in JMeter I can specify cookie policy and Implementation. Analogous scenario in JMeter works. My scenario:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class TestScenario extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("https://test.test.net")
        .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.css""", """.*\.js""", """.*\.jpg""", """.*\.png""", """.*\.gif""", """.*\.ico"""), WhiteList())
        .acceptHeader("application/json, text/plain, */*")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate, br")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
        .connectionHeader("close")
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")
        //.disableAutomaticReferer

    val headers_standard = Map(
        "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "Accept-Language" -> "pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
        "User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.3;WOW64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/48.0.2564.116Safari/537.36")

    val headers_referer = Map(
        "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "Accept-Language" -> "pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
        "User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.3;WOW64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/48.0.2564.116Safari/537.36",
        "Referer" -> "https://test.test.net")

    val headers = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json;charset=utf-8")

    val uri1 = "https://test.test.net:443"
    val uri2 = "https://test.test.net:443"

    val scn = scenario("Test scenario")
        .exec(
            http("First step")
                .get("/main").headers(headers_standard)
                .disableFollowRedirect 
                .check(
                  status.is(302)
                )
        )
        .exec(
            http("Login Service")
                .get(uri1 + "/login?service= https%3A%2F%test.test.net")
                .headers(headers_standard)
                .disableFollowRedirect
                .check(
                  status.is(401),
                  regex("""input type="hidden" name="execution" value=""").exists,
                  regex("""input type="hidden" name="execution" value="(.+?)"""").saveAs("execution")
                )
        )
        .exec(
            http("Log in")
              .post(uri1 + "/login?service=https%3A%2F%test.test.net")
                .headers(headers_referer)
                .disableFollowRedirect
              .formParam("username", """user""")
                .formParam("password", "pass")
                .formParam("execution", "${execution}")
                .formParam("_eventId", "submit")
                .check(
                    status.is(302),
                    headerRegex("Location", "ticket=(.+).dev").saveAs("ticket")
                    )
        )
        .exec(
            http("Ticket")
              .get("/")
              .queryParam("ticket","${ticket}.dev")
              .headers(headers_referer)
              .check(
                 status.is(200),
                 regex("""<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5""").exists
                  )
    )
        .exec(
        http("user")
          .get("/user")
          .headers(headers)
          .disableFollowRedirect
          .check(
              status.is(200),
              regex("""Work in the""").exists
              )
    )
        .exec(
            http("Log out")
                .get(uri1 + "/logout")
                .headers(headers)
                .check(
                    status.is(200),
                    regex("""Successful log out""").exists
                    )
      )

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Comment: run it in Debug mode and see whats the error ..this does not looks like a Gatling issue ... when you send a request what does the logs complain ..the application logs

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you have to enable the follow redirects. Then status response would be 200. Try this. Hope it will be help you...`
.exec(
            http("First step")
                .get("/main").headers(headers_standard)
                .check(status.is(200)
                )
        )...